# ncp module file copy issue Error: EPERM, unlink

Tags: node.js

```
ncp('/dir/to/copy/from', '/dir/to/copy/to', function (err) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  // done
});
```

I am using ncp module to copy files recursively and works perfectly fine.
I often get the error:
Error: EPERM, unlink '\dir\path\sourcefile\

and it crashes:
 [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... 
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?